# LSTM for HSI data classification

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to classify the [Pavia University HSI data](https://www.kaggle.com/syamkakarla/pavia-university-hsi) using LSTM. The X_train data is of the shape (610x340, 103) and y_train data is of the shape (610x340). There are totally 9 classes. So, I have 207400 samples with 103 features (1 feature per each timestep). How should I reshape my data where each sample is a time series of 103 time steps with one feature in order to classify using LSTM?

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to pass your data through Embedding layer which takes input of 2D format (sample, time steps) and projects it to 3D (sample, time steps, features).

Thus output from Embedding layer can be transfer to LSTM layer in Keras LSTM layer which accepts 3D tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Since your y_train has 9 classes and is of shape (610x340), I think you are having class labels in y_train which you need to convert to binary (1/0) for each labels. As a result for each row in y_train you will have 9 columns and your final y_train should be of shape (207400, 9). you can use keras.utils.to_categorical for that. Then your X_train needs to be reshaped in the order (N_observations, n_time_steps, n_variables). you can do this by reshaping first to (610X340X103, 1) or (21362200, 1) and then reshaping to (207400, 103, 1)

Comment: I have reshaped my X_train and y_train into (207400,103) and (207400,) respectively. Now should I set my input_shape dimension to (103,1)?

Comment: your X_train needs to be of shape (207400, 103, 1) and y_train needs to be (207400, 9) as you have 9 classes. your input_shape dimension for LSTM should be (103, 1) and network needs to end with 9 nodes